# Multiple virtualhosts with the same servername

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have an apache server, a unique domain name and multiple tomcat instances, here is my actual config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName my.domain.com
...
ProxyPass /sample_1 ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/sample_1 
ProxyPass /sample_2 ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/sample_2 
ProxyPass /sample_3 ajp://127.0.0.1:8014/sample_3
ProxyPass /sample_4 ajp://127.0.0.1:8019/sample_4
....
CustomLog   logs/my_access_log combined
ErrorLog    logs/my_error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I would like to use a CustomLog for each tomcat instance, I tried to put each ProxyPass directive in a separate virtualhost, but I got 403 error except for the virtualhost on the top according to httpd -S output.

I don't like to remove the ServerName directive, because the service will be available throug the IP address.

Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) directive in combination with [conditional logging](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog)  to log specific requests to different log files.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName my.example.com
    ...

    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/sample_1.*" sample_1
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/sample_2.*" sample_2

    CustomLog   logs/my_access_log_sample_1 combined env=sample_1
    CustomLog   logs/my_access_log_sample_2 combined env=sample_2
    CustomLog   logs/my_access_log combined
    ErrorLog    logs/my_error_log

</VirtualHost>
```